# Counting and grouping items by relative position. grouping by 5's for instance

Tags: php, javascript

The idea is that there will be a php function that echo's html for every image in a directory(scandir)

I figure using a for each(something like) to walk through that array and assigns the values to img src values

but in order for there to be a function that assigns class values that would allow for

scripted rather than manual css positioning I need to be able to assign classes based on

relative position in a grouping of objects. for instance, there are 50 images in a directory the scandir returns an array of those files a function generates img tags for each item assigns class (a function in a variable to accomplish this, i suspect) by cycling through 5 classes  with the output being like

```
<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
<img class="c" src="example">
<img class="d" src="example">
<img class="e" src="example">

<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
<img class="c" src="example">
<img class="d" src="example">
<img class="e" src="example">


<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
<img class="c" src="example">
<img class="d" src="example">
<img class="e" src="example">


<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
<img class="c" src="example">
<img class="d" src="example">
<img class="e" src="example">


<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
<img class="c" src="example">
<img class="d" src="example">
<img class="e" src="example">


<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
<img class="c" src="example">
<img class="d" src="example">
<img class="e" src="example">
```

now the numbers 50 & 5 are hypothetical, I will more likely using class assignment cycles of 7 or 12

really please how do I do this? I'm just learning on my own and it's really important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cycle = 5;    
$classes = array( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' );
$i = 0;
foreach( $files as $file ) {
    echo '<img class="'.$classes[ $i % $cycle ].'" src="'.$file.'">';
    ++$i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for the modulo operator. I think it's available in javascript as well, the following is a PHP example which uses it in two places.

1. To cycle through an array of available class names.
2. To insert a line-break after each X images.

The [modulo operator `%`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) return the leftover value of a division operation.

[Demo](http://codepad.org/Q3MfQt3V):

```
$images = array_fill(0, 50, 'example'); // 50 example images
$classes = range('a', 'e'); // 5 example classes (a-e)

foreach($images as $index => $src)
{
    # get image class    
    $class = $classes[$index % count($classes)];

    printf('<img class="%s" src="%s">'."\n", $class, $src);

    # echo empty line after each 5th image
    if (4 === $index % 5)
        echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
<img class="c" src="example">
<img class="d" src="example">
<img class="e" src="example">

<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
<img class="c" src="example">
<img class="d" src="example">
<img class="e" src="example">

<img class="a" src="example">
<img class="b" src="example">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `cycle` method like the one defined in [this snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3399).

This will cycle through values in an array eg. `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `reset_cycle` will reset the cycle if necessary, although I don't think this use-case would require a reset.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a modulo (%) to make this happen.
In your loop keep track of a number counting how much iterations you've had of the loop. Then use the modulo to assign a different class to the html. For instance:

```
$rowCount = 5; //number of images in a row
$i = 1;
foreach($images as $image) {
    $classNumber = $i % $rowCount;
    echo '<img class="image_' . $classNumber . '" src="example">';
    $i++;
}
```

I wrote this from the top of my head without testing, so there could be an error in there somewhere, but it's to give you an idea what you could do.
Check out [this tiny example](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php). Or google for "php modulo".

I hope this helps.